Adding a column with formula driven text and amounts
I have a spreadsheet and I need to add up column with both text and monetary amounts in.  But, because what I am trying to total are the results of a formula, I can't get it right.
My spreadsheet is recording sessions taken.  So if the 8 - 9 session is used, put a 1 in.  On the invoice that records £20, if an 'F' is put in the session,  then the invoice records 'Funded'.  How can I total this column please?
I've tried =VALUE(SUMIF(C23:H23,">0")) and that doesn't work!
Thanks in advance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The description of your spreadsheet is inevitably less clear than some sample data and the expected outcome. (what is "the 8 - 9 session"? where do you put a 1 in? etc.  As it is, looking at the formula you have tried, we have no idea what in C24:H23

The formula SUMIF(C23:H23,">0") can get the sum of umbers greater than 0, if this does not work, please share us a simple sample.
